# Git + Symfony project to serve multiple individual website installations

Tags: git, symfony, templates, multisite

I have a Symfony project tracked with Git which I will soon need to duplicate for making multiple (separate) sister websites. These sites will have:

- same logic;
- same database schema;
- same everything

The only differences between the individual sites will be:

- database contents (not relevant here);
- different look (therefore different contents of the /templates folder and probably /assets too).

Of course making copies of the repository for every site would be a suicidal move, as every change or extension to the logic would require every copy to be updated.
I need to keep the application code as a single Git repo, and track and manage the views somehow differently.

The solution I have been thinking about is the following:

1. Create a subfolder for the views of each individual site: /templates/site1, ..., /templates/siteN
2. Stop tracking the /templates folder from the main Git repo, and treat the subfolders /templates/site<?> as additional site-specific repositories (or don't track them at all)
3. Add an extra variable in the .env file, eg. TEMPLATES_FOLDER="/site1"
4. Modify all the controllers so whenever a view is loaded, such string is added to the path

Solved, I think?
Whenever in development I am working at a specific site, I just edit the TEMPLATES_FOLDER variable and it's like switching looks very quickly, so I can work at the specific views, or just at the main common app.
On the individual production sites I can even put the specific templates directly under /templates, and set TEMPLATES_FOLDER="" in the .env file: that would have the same behaviour of a standard Symfony installation.

I don't see any problem with this, but I am a relative beginner and I haven't found anything like this online, so I suspect things may be more complicated than I think and I am missing something.
Before I proceed tweaking my project I would like to hear a few opinions.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO e.g the templates-dir could be a nested git repository that is not tracked by the "core-repository". I dont mean  as a git submodule but as a real nested git repository, this would give you flexibility to easy maintain core on all sites while have different repositories checked out into templates dir, you also would not have to edit the template-path with .env or similiar as the folder will have always the same name

Comment: @johnSmith if I understood your idea correctly, it should be the same thing I have thought: nested repositories for each website's layout, not tracked by the 'core repository'.
The template path in the .env file is useful to select a specific layout for development purposes, otherwise the symfony installation wouldn't run locally because the /templates folders contains an extra level of subfolders

Comment: yes it´s basically the same :) A slightly different option could be that the templates dir is a single repository as well but you have a branch per site, so you would check out the according branch to the according site.